# JS Color Guessing Game - Background color change

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm trying to solve a color guessing game assignment. Everything works fine except the last part where page's color should change according to the color that is guessed.

Would really appreciate any tips!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript Guessing Color</title>
</head>
<body onload = "doGame()">

<script>

var colors = ["Azure", "Black", "Chocolate", "Cyan", "Grey", "Green", "Ivory", "Lavender", "Navy", "Olive", "Turquoise", "Yellow"];
var target;
var choice;
var numOfGame = 0;
var finished = false;


function doGame(){
    var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
    target = colors[randNum];
    alert(colors[randNum]);

    while (!finished) {
        choice = prompt("Please, guess the color. \n\n Possible colors are: " + colors + ".\n\n" + "What is the color?");
        numOfGame++;
        finished = checkGuess();
    }
}

function checkGuess() {
    if  ( colors.indexOf(choice) === -1) {
        alert("I don’t recognize that color!");
        return false;
    } else  if (choice > target) {
        alert("Your color is alphabetically higher than mine. Please, try again");
        return false;
    } else if (choice < target) {
        alert("Your color is alphabetically lower than mine. Please, try again");
        return false; 
    } else {
        alert("You won! Number of games played is " + numOfGame);
        return true;
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = target;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You return prior to the changes (making the changes unreachable). As there's already a correct answer, can you mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is returning from checkGuess() before changing the color. So, Put

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = target;
```

before the statement

```
return true;
```

Check this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/anuranpal/x4p7grtu/